# How to call a function in child component from parent listview

Tags: react-native

I have a navigation from (parent component) listView:

```
rowPressed(element) {
    this.props.navigator.push({
           title: element.title,
           rightButtonSystemIcon: 'action',
    onRightButtonPress: () => {
      // how to call my function _handleRightButtonPress() ?
    },
           component: ElementDetail,
           passProps: {
             element: element
           }
       });
  }
```

I would like to call _handleRightButtonPress() on ElementDetail component:

```
class ElementDetail extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    ...
  }

  _handleRightButtonPress() {
    console.log('right Button Pressed');
  };

...

}
```

Any ideas how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is for the parent to pass a function to the child. The child can use that function to communicate with its parent.

The parent would pass a function to the child as a prop, like this:

```
<MyChild myFunc={this.handleChildFunc.bind(this)} />
```

And the child would call that function like so:

```
this.props.myFunc();
And don't forget that the child will need this function declared in its propTypes:

MyChild.propTypes = {
  myFunc: React.PropTypes.func,
};
```

For more details regarding communication between components Refer [Link](http://andrewhfarmer.com/component-communication/)

Comment: Thank you. But how can I call this function in child component from "onRightButtonPress" located in Parent class?

Comment: you can use react-redux and sent some data along which will get invoked on the child component once the component receive the props via redux.